# Does Microsoft Office offer you free online storage like Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, onedrive, office-365, online-storage

Does Microsoft offer anything in terms of online storage, something similar to Google Docs?

I'm thinking of just keeping a few essential files on the "cloud", so I'll need as little as 50MB.

Is there a Microsoft Office Online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Windows Live Skydrive](http://www.windowslive.co.uk/skydrive) is probably what you're after. 25GB storage with a web-based interface. Slightly more than 50Mb than you want, but free to anybody with a hotmail/msn account.

Comment: http://workspace.officelive.com/en-us/Office-Web-Applications

Comment: JL: Office Live is closing and it's being replaced by SkyDrive. One of my Office Live accounts has already been migrated.

Comment: @Jason, Will the web based office editor still be available in SkyDrive?

Comment: @JL01: Yes.  The Office Web Apps are actually part of SkyDrive and never were part of Office Live.  That Office Live page just redirects to SkyDrive, as they are closing it down.  There are also Office Web Apps in SharePoint and Facebook Docs www.docs.com.

Comment: The link returns "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

Answer (score 4):

You could also use Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

The current name of the Microsoft online storage for consumers is [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/).

Regarding Office Online, the current name is Office 365. It's a subscription based service.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Live Mesh

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-devices-help-center

Comment: It's better to use SkyDrive for this, as Office 2010 has support for SkyDrive built-in.  You can open and save documents directly to SkyDrive.

Comment: It looks that Windows Live Mesh is not available anymore.